# ListView null in Framgment/PageAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm creating a basic android app, and used the default created to create the first activity. This Activity has the PageAdapter. I want to have different layouts in each of the pages, and would like a `ListView` in the first so I did this:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int page = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER); 
            switch(page){
            case 1:
                SettingListAdapter settingAdapter = new SettingListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.setting_item_row, MainFeedActivity.mProfileList);
                ListView listView = (ListView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                listView.setAdapter(settingAdapter); 
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break; 
            }
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_feed_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

But my `ListView` is returning `null` and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me as to what I'm doing wrong with my code?

Here is the entire class if you need it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.RequestBatch;
import com.redclay.fanaddict.R;
import com.redclay.fanaddict.helpers.Parser;
import com.redclay.fanaddict.helpers.SettingListAdapter;
import com.redclay.fanaddict.models.DeviceSettings;
import com.redclay.fanaddict.models.UserProfile;

public class MainFeedActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private String jsonResponse = null; 
    private static DeviceSettings mDeviceSettings;
    private static List<UserProfile> mProfileList = new ArrayList<UserProfile>(); 
    public static List<Long> mProfileIdList = new ArrayList<Long>(); 
    private final String URL = "http://fanaddictsweb.redcley.com/Services/UserProfileService.svc/2/login";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_feed);

        RequestUserFeed feed = new RequestUserFeed(); 
        feed.execute(URL); 

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);






    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_feed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_main_feed).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_settings).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_about).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int page = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER); 
            switch(page){
            case 1:
                SettingListAdapter settingAdapter = new SettingListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.setting_item_row, MainFeedActivity.mProfileList);
                ListView listView = (ListView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                listView.setAdapter(settingAdapter); 
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break; 
            }
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_feed_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    class RequestUserFeed extends AsyncTask<String, String, HttpResponse>{
        HttpResponse response = null; 

        @Override
        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri[0]); 
            post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
                json.put("UserName", "michigan");
                json.put("Password", "fanaddicts");
                json.put("DeviceHardwareId", "NW58xfxz/w+jCiI3E592degUCL4=");
                json.put("DeviceTypeId", "1");
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 
                Log.i("Feed Request", "SE: " + json.toString()); 
                post.setEntity(se);

                response = httpClient.execute(post); 

                Log.i("Feed Response", "Feed: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); 

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {
            HttpEntity entity = result.getEntity(); 

            try {
                jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
                System.out.println("Resposne: " + jsonResponse );
                Parser parser = new Parser(jsonResponse); 
                MainFeedActivity.mDeviceSettings = parser.getmDeviceSettings(); 
                MainFeedActivity.mProfileList = parser.getmProfileList(); 
                MainFeedActivity.mProfileIdList = parser.getUserProfileIds(MainFeedActivity.mProfileList);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }


    }

    class RequestSocialMediaFeeds extends AsyncTask<List<Long>, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(List<Long>... arg0) {
            List<Long> mList = arg0[0]; 
            RequestBatch batch = new RequestBatch(); 

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating the `Fragment`'s layout after the `ListView` initialization.

```
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_feed_dummy,
                    container, false);
```

should come before

```
ListView listView = (ListView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```